# Mysql search performance on big data

Tags: mysql, database, search, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My application is running on the Amazon cloud, though I'm experiencing problems when using mysql as the core. The application will be an archive for emails.

Mysql will keep metadata of the e-mails as following (inside a Amazon RDS database)

```
- emails
 id (int)
 account_id (int)
 subject (varchar(255))
 date (datetime)
 fingerprint (varchar(64))
 subject (text)
 messagetext (longtext)
```

The full EML files are stored on the Amazon S3 and can be found after the id field of emails table. Everything is working fine but I'm getting performance issues very quickly. There can be easily 10 - 20k emails per account and I'm having about 2 to 3k accounts that need to be connected in this db. Im storing the metadata of the emails so they are searchable.

Even on a Medium DB instance (multi a-z, http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) I get (big) performance decreases after there ~200 accounts in (2 mil records). Even simple selects (with limits ofcourse) are running alot slower. In addition, inserts and updates take a lot longer.

The index size is around 500MB and the total table size is around 9GB.

Alternatives like Amazon cloudsearch seems expensive ($0.98 per GB + $0.1 per 1k batch uploads (max 5MB)). The advantage of the Amazon RDS is that it's easy to create a reliable DB (back-ups, multi a-z).

--
Example queries (but even the first one is significantly slower to like 1s instead of a couple ms):

```
"SELECT * FROM emails WHERE id = '10' LIMIT 1;"

"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails WHERE account_id = '5' LIMIT 1;"

"SELECT id, subject FROM emails WHERE subject LIKE '%query%' LIMIT 10;"
```

Comment: and your sql query is??? that is causing the delays?  Are indexes available to optimize your criteria?  Show that and an "EXPLAIN SELECT ..." to possibly help.

Comment: Added examples in the message above, though it seems like just every query that used to take <50ms takes over a second.